# How to get small error text inside input box when email is invalid

Tags: html, css, validation, text, input

I am attempting to add small red text inside the email input box when the user's email is incorrect.  The code is correctly recognizing if the email is valid and showing the correct red x icon if it is not valid; however, I would like to add a small amount of text inside the input box.  If someone knows how to complete this your help would be appreciated!

[Small red text inside input box](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uuR7w.png)

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/M6N24/524/)

My html:

```
<form class="container" action="https://webto.salesforce.com/servlet/servlet.WebToLead?encoding=UTF-8" method="POST">
    <label>
        First Name
        <input id="first_name" maxlength="40" name="first_name" size="20" type="text" onkeyup="test()" required><i class="fa fa-check-circle" aria-hidden="true"></i>
    </label>
    <label>
        Last Name
        <input id="last_name" maxlength="80" name="last_name" size="20" type="text" onkeyup="test()"><i class="fa fa-check-circle" aria-hidden="true"></i>
    </label>
    <label>
        Email
        <input id="email" maxlength="80" name="email" size="20" type="text" onkeyup="test()"><i class="fa fa-times-circle-o" aria-hidden="true"></i>
    </label>
    <label>
        Phone
        <input id="phone" maxlength="40" name="phone" size="20" type="text" onkeyup="test()"><i class="fa fa-check-circle" aria-hidden="true"></i>
    </label>
    <label>
        City
        <input id="city" name="city" maxlength="40" size="20" type="text" onkeyup="test()"><i class="fa fa-check-circle" aria-hidden="true"></i>
    </label>
    <label>
        State/Province
        <input id="state" maxlength="20" name="state" size="20" type="text" onkeyup="test()"><i class="fa fa-check-circle" aria-hidden="true"></i>
    </label>
    <label id="co">
        Company
        <input id="company" name="company" type="text" onkeyup="test()"><i class="fa fa-check-circle" aria-hidden="true"></i>
    </label>
    <label>
        Comments
        <textarea id="comments" name="" id="" cols="30" rows="10" onkeyup="test()"></textarea>
        <input id="sub" type="submit" disabled="disabled" />
    </label>

    <div>
        <select hidden="true" id="00N6A000008yXMN" name="00N6A000008yXMN" title="Product Interest">
            <option value="">--None--</option>
            <option selected="selected" value="Visiant">Visiant</option>
            <option value="Tessellate">Tessellate</option>
        </select><br>

        <select hidden="true" id="lead_source" name="lead_source">
            <option value="">--None--</option>
            <option value="Internal">Internal</option>
            <option value="Trade Show">Trade Show</option>
            <option selected="selected" value="Website">Website</option>
            <option value="Direct Marketing">Direct Marketing</option>
            <option value="Social Media">Social Media</option>
            <option value="Other">Other</option>
        </select><br>
    </div>
</form>
```

My JS:

```
function validateEmail(email) {
    var re = /^(([^<>()[\]\\.,;:\s@\"]+(\.[^<>()[\]\\.,;:\s@\"]+)*)|(\".+\"))@((\[[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\])|(([a-zA-Z\-0-9]+\.)+[a-zA-Z]{2,}))$/;
        return re.test(email);
    }

    $('input[type="text"]').on('keyup', function() {
    if ($(this).val().trim() != '') {
        if ($(this).is('#email')) {
            if (validateEmail($(this).val())) {
                $(this).attr('data-valid','valid');
            } else {
                $(this).attr('data-valid','error');
                console.log("this works")
            }
        } else {
            $(this).attr('data-valid','valid');
            console.log("this works")

        }
    } else {
        $(this).removeAttr('data-valid');
        console.log("this works")
    }
});

test = function() {
    if($("#first_name").val() && $("#last_name").val() && $("#email").val() && $("#phone").val() && $("#city").val() && $("#state").val() && $("#company").val()){
        $("#sub").removeAttr("disabled");
    }
}
```

My CSS:

```
body {
    color: #fff;
    background-color: #f78e2a;
    text-align: center;
}

form {
    color: #fff;
    background-color: #f78e2a;
    text-align: center;
    font-family: Lato;
}

* {
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

.form-title {
    font-size: 38px;
    color: #fff;
    font-family: "Lato";
    letter-spacing: 70px;
}

input[type="text"] {
    width: 100%;
    padding: 10px;
    background-color: #f9a558;
    border: 1px solid #fff;
}

input[type="text"]:focus {
    background-color: #fff;
}

input[type="text"]:visited {
    background-color: #fff;
}

.container {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    padding: 5px 0;
    margin-left: 10%;
    margin-right: 10%;
}

textarea {
    width: 100%;
    background-color: #f9a558;
    border: 1px solid #fff;
}

textarea:focus {
    background-color: #fff;
}

#co {
    flex-basis: 100%;
    max-width: 100%;
}

label:nth-last-child(-n+2) {
    flex-basis: 100%;
    max-width: 100%;
}

select,
    label {
    height: 50px;
    width: 48%;
    margin: 2% 1%;
    text-align: left;
    font-family: "Lato";
}

#sub {
    border-radius: 6px;
    width: 120px;
    height: 35px;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    display: block;
    margin-top: 10px;

}

button {
    margin-top: 10px;
    background-color: #B9B9B9;
    color: #959595;
    border-radius: 6px;
    width: 120px;
    height: 35px;
    margin-left: 1%;
    display: block;
}


button:focus {
    background-color: #fff;
    color: #f78e2a;
}

@media (max-width: 426px) {
    label {
        width: 98%;
    }
}

@media (min-width: 426px) {
    .container {
    flex-direction: row;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    align-self: flex-start;
}
}

label {
    position: relative;
}

.fa {
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;
    right: 0;
    transform: translate(-50%, -5%);
    opacity: 0;
    transition: opacity .5s, color .5s;
}


[data-valid] + .fa {
    opacity: 1;
    color: green;
}

[data-valid="valid"] + .fa {
    color: green;
}

[data-valid="error"] + .fa {
    color: red;
}
```

Comment: Have you tried anything?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Changed your code so that the parent `label` manages the state of the `input`, instead of the `input` holding the state. Then you can nest an element that holds the error text in the `label`, hide it by default, then show it if the parent `label` has `data-valid="error"` state.

You can play around with the positioning to get the spacing/font-size where you want it.

```js
function validateEmail(email) {
  var re = /^(([^<>()[\]\\.,;:\s@\"]+(\.[^<>()[\]\\.,;:\s@\"]+)*)|(\".+\"))@((\[[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\])|(([a-zA-Z\-0-9]+\.)+[a-zA-Z]{2,}))$/;
  return re.test(email);
}

$('input[type="text"]').on('keyup', function() {
  var $label = $(this).closest('label');
  if ($(this).val().trim() != '') {
    if ($(this).is('#email')) {
      if (validateEmail($(this).val())) {
        $label.attr('data-valid', 'valid');
      } else {
        $label.attr('data-valid', 'error');
        console.log("this works")
      }
    } else {
      $label.attr('data-valid', 'valid');
      console.log("this works")
    }
  } else {
    $label.removeAttr('data-valid');
    console.log("this works")

  }
});


test = function() {
  if ($("#first_name").val() && $("#last_name").val() && $("#email").val() && $("#phone").val() && $("#city").val() && $("#state").val() && $("#company").val()) {
    $("#sub").removeAttr("disabled");
  }
}
```

```css
body {
  color: #fff;
  background-color: #f78e2a;
  text-align: center;
}

form {
  color: #fff;
  background-color: #f78e2a;
  text-align: center;
  font-family: Lato;
}

* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.form-title {
  font-size: 38px;
  color: #fff;
  font-family: "Lato";
  letter-spacing: 70px;
}

input[type="text"] {
  width: 100%;
  padding: 10px;
  background-color: #f9a558;
  border: 1px solid #fff;
}

input[type="text"]:focus {
  background-color: #fff;
}

input[type="text"]:visited {
  background-color: #fff;
}

.container {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  padding: 5px 0;
  margin-left: 10%;
  margin-right: 10%;
}

textarea {
  width: 100%;
  background-color: #f9a558;
  border: 1px solid #fff;
}

textarea:focus {
  background-color: #fff;
}

#co {
  flex-basis: 100%;
  max-width: 100%;
}

label:nth-last-child(-n+2) {
  flex-basis: 100%;
  max-width: 100%;
}

select,
label {
  height: 50px;
  width: 48%;
  margin: 2% 1%;
  text-align: left;
  font-family: "Lato";
}

#sub {
  border-radius: 6px;
  width: 120px;
  height: 35px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  display: block;
  margin-top: 10px;
}

button {
  margin-top: 10px;
  background-color: #B9B9B9;
  color: #959595;
  border-radius: 6px;
  width: 120px;
  height: 35px;
  margin-left: 1%;
  display: block;
}

button:focus {
  background-color: #fff;
  color: #f78e2a;
}

@media (max-width: 426px) {
  label {
    width: 98%;
  }
}

@media (min-width: 426px) {
  .container {
    flex-direction: row;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    align-self: flex-start;
  }
}

label {
  position: relative;
}

.fa {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  right: 0;
  transform: translate(-50%, -5%);
  opacity: 0;
  transition: opacity .5s, color .5s;
}

[data-valid] .fa {
  opacity: 1;
  color: green;
}

[data-valid="valid"] .fa {
  color: green;
}

[data-valid="error"] .fa {
  color: red;
}

.error {
  display: none;
  color: red;
  font-size: .7em;
  position: absolute;
  left: 10px;
  top: 0;
  transform: translateY(150%);
}

[data-valid="error"] .error {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.0.3/css/font-awesome.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<form class="container" action="https://webto.salesforce.com/servlet/servlet.WebToLead?encoding=UTF-8" method="POST">
  <label>First Name
    <input id="first_name" maxlength="40" name="first_name" size="20" type="text" onkeyup="test()" required><i class="fa fa-check-circle" aria-hidden="true"></i>
  </label>
  <label>Last Name
    <input id="last_name" maxlength="80" name="last_name" size="20" type="text" onkeyup="test()"><i class="fa fa-check-circle" aria-hidden="true"></i>
  </label>
  <label>Email
    <span class="error">Please enter a valid email address</span>
    <input id="email" maxlength="80" name="email" size="20" type="text" onkeyup="test()"><i class="fa fa-times-circle-o" aria-hidden="true"></i>
  </label>
  <label>Phone
    <input id="phone" maxlength="40" name="phone" size="20" type="text" onkeyup="test()"><i class="fa fa-check-circle" aria-hidden="true"></i>
  </label>
  <label>City
    <input id="city" name="city" maxlength="40" size="20" type="text" onkeyup="test()"><i class="fa fa-check-circle" aria-hidden="true"></i>
  </label>
  <label>State/Province
    <input id="state" maxlength="20" name="state" size="20" type="text" onkeyup="test()"><i class="fa fa-check-circle" aria-hidden="true"></i>
  </label>
  <label id="co">Company
    <input id="company" name="company" type="text" onkeyup="test()"><i class="fa fa-check-circle" aria-hidden="true"></i>
  </label>
  <label>Comments
    <textarea id="comments" name="" id="" cols="30" rows="10" onkeyup="test()"></textarea>
    <input id="sub" type="submit" disabled="disabled" />
  </label>

  <div>
    <select hidden="true" id="00N6A000008yXMN" name="00N6A000008yXMN" title="Product Interest">
      <option value="">--None--</option>
      <option selected="selected" value="Visiant">Visiant</option>
      <option value="Tessellate">Tessellate</option>
    </select>
    <br>

    <select hidden="true" id="lead_source" name="lead_source">
      <option value="">--None--</option>
      <option value="Internal">Internal</option>
      <option value="Trade Show">Trade Show</option>
      <option selected="selected" value="Website">Website</option>
      <option value="Direct Marketing">Direct Marketing</option>
      <option value="Social Media">Social Media</option>
      <option value="Other">Other</option>
    </select>
    <br>
  </div>
</form>
```

Comment: Thank you so much again.  This worked like a charm.  You are on fire.  I have another question regarding phone number validation that I will be posting shortly if you would like to take a look!

Comment: Guess I can only post every 90 minutes.  I will post it then.